# MySQL InnoDB Slow - Order By Case When

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a table with a field flag with a value of 0, 1 or 2. I need to order the results with a flag value of 2 first followed by the remaining results.

At the moment I am using `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY CASE WHEN flag = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0` and while this worked fine (<0.1s) on MyISAM, this appears very slow (9s for 10k rows) on InnoDB (something we are moving over to).

I've tried `ORDER BY FIELD (flag, '2') DESC` with similar results.

`flag` has an index and works very quick if I do a simple `ORDER BY flag DESC`, but this gives priority to those with flag 1 over those with flag 0, something I don't want.

Is there any tweaking of InnoDB that could help, or is there a more efficient way of ordering these results?

Comment: (1) I am surprised that MyISAM is so much faster.  (2) I don't know if you can get the index to be used for the `ORDER BY`.  (3) 9 seconds to sort 10k rows seems slow.

Comment: If you're going to down vote, do please explain why and if there's more information I should provide.

Comment: 9 seconds for only 10K rows?  No way.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.  _Something else_ is going on.  Such as the datatype of `flag`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the thoughts on alternative approaches to the ordering problem.

However, the issue lies with the InnoDB settings of `my.ini`:

```
# 60-80 % of available RAM.
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1024M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 128M

# 25 % of buffer pool size.
innodb_log_file_size = 256M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 128M
```

It appears that using InnoDB requires some configuring of `my.cnf`; I am used to MyISAM that requires very little.

Obviously there's plenty of reading to do, including the links below, but hopefully this will help others get started as it has myself:

[MySQL Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/optimizing-innodb-diskio.html)

[One of Many Third Party Articles](https://www.percona.com/blog/2015/06/02/80-ram-tune-innodb_buffer_pool_size/)

Answer (score 0):

Are you tried?:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY (flag = 2) DESC
```

Comment: I like the alternative approach to the ordering (one I wasn't familiar with) which works to order as I need but I get the same slow result.